# I made a prime number checker in python. Can it be optimized?

Tags: python

I made a simple little prime number checker in python as my first project while learning. How can it be improved? For example, is this the most compact I can make it?

```
def isPrime(input):
    check = input - 1
    checkmod = input % check
    for i in range (input):
        checkmod = input % check
        check -=1

        if checkmod != 0 and input > 1 and check <= 1 or input == 2:
            return 'Prime'

        elif checkmod == 0 and check > 1:
            return 'Not prime'

print(isPrime(numberhere)) # where to put in number
```

Comment: If the code works as you expect, then perhaps [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question.

Comment: The answer to this question is a gigantic can of worms.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution would be:

```
def isprime(num):
    if not (isinstance(num,int)):    #checking number should be integer
        return "Enter a valid number"
    elif (num < 0):    #checking number should be positive
        return "Enter a positive number"
    else:
        for i in range(2,num):    #start the loop from 2 upto number
            if num % i == 0:      #checking prime condition
                return "Number is not Prime"    #if found not prime return here
                break    #and exit from loop
        else:
            return "Number is Prime"     #if found prime return here

print(isprime(7))    #calling the method here
```

Ofcourse there are many ways to optimize the prime number program. below are few links which will help you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

https://web.archive.org/web/20080324064651/http://krenzel.info/?p=83

Answer (score 0):

Respectful of the comments by @Shadow and @Scott, there are a few things that could be written differently. Since you're learning python, I find this could still be useful to you. I will start commenting your original code:

```
def isPrime(input):
    check = input - 1
    checkmod = input % check    # checkmod is recalculated in the loop: eliminate
    for i in range (input):
        checkmod = input % check
        check -=1

        # The test condition below can be simplified. For example, you
        # test that input>1 or input==2 at every loop, when in fact input
        # never changes after entering the function. I think that those
        # two tests should shortcut at the very beginning. 
        #
        if checkmod != 0 and input > 1 and check <= 1 or input == 2:
            return 'Prime'

        # Not sure if this is an optimization, but the two statements
        # seem quite separate. I would use either "else" or just simply
        # another "if"
        elif checkmod == 0 and check > 1:
            return 'Not prime'
```

So this leaves us with this version of the function: I doubt it's much faster, but there are some nuggets in there that I think are useful. You will be the judge anyway :-)

```
def isPrime(input):
    # room here to test input>=1
    if input in [1, 2]:
        return 'Prime'
    # if you work out the sequence of values for check
    # they can be generated via range(). Mindful though
    # that the comparison has to be adjusted against (i-1)
    # which can be simplified by moving -1 to the other side
    # hence comparing against 2
    #
    for i in range(input-1, 0, -1):
        checkmod = input % i
        if checkmod != 0 and i <= 2:
            return 'Prime'
        if checkmod == 0 and i > 2:
            return 'Not prime'

numberhere = 22
print(isPrime(numberhere))  # where to put in number
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might be faster:

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    ''' return True if n is a prime number. False otherwise.'''
    # negative numbers, 0, and 1 are not prime
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    # 2 is prime
    if n == 2:
        return True
    # non-2 even numbers are not prime
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    # loop through odd divisors up to its sqrt
    for i in range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)), 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Reference (Socratica):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2p3kwF04xcA

Answer (score 0):

This is a script to check if the inputted number is prime in one line. It will return 'True' if the number is prime else 'False'.

```
# If num is bigger than 1, and is 2 or is odd, and when divided by all the number from 3 to num's square root plus 1 (excluding even numbers), there is always a remainder.
def primes(num): return True if num > 1 and (num == 2 or num % 2 != 0) and all(num % divisor != 0 for divisor in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2)) else False


print(primes(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter number"))
for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
    if n % i == 0:
        print(n, "is Not Prime Number")
        break
else:
    print(n, "is Prime number")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?